# Iterating through 2 lists and returning values in corresponding positions

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to iterate through two list, return the first from each list and assign these values as arguments to a function. This is what I have tried, but this returns 3*3 arguments, for each iteration of the first list, it will return 3 iterations from the second_list, whereas I would like to simply take the first element of list 1 and list 2 and assign to function, then the second item etc:

```
files = ['Sessiontoleadprobabs','leadtoopportunityprobabs','opportunitytocompleteprobabs']
sims_list = list(sims.columns)
for i in files:
    for j in range(0,len(sims_list)):
        func(sims=sims,actual=i,col_name=sims[str(sims_list[j])])
```

This are the list of columns (sims_list):

```
session_to_leads
lead_to_opps
oops_to_comp
```

Comment: So you just want to call the function 3 times? with (1,1),(2,2) and (3,3)

Comment: @ansev pretty much

Comment: I don't understand. The first element of each list only or all pared?

Comment: @Pynchia all paired

Comment: You have a good answer already then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use zip like below

```py
for val1, val2 in zip(files, sim_list):
    func(val1,val2)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler `for` loops, assuming `sims` is a DataFrame:

```
for i, col in enumerate(sims.columns):
    func(sims=sims,actual=i,col_name=sims[col])
```